# Compute standard deviation for each row and by group based on a specific variable

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, statistics, standard-deviation

I am fresh user of python, my issue is to compute standard deviation for the column *residual*.
to do it :

1. I have to calculate the mean residual in each group
2. I need the size of ID for each group

I happened to do some calculation and this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from statistics import stdev
import statistics
from math import * 

#Enumerate the data 1,2,3.. for each variable 
A['Rec'] = A.groupby(['code ']).cumcount().add(1)

## Defining companies by their IDs
A['ID']=A.groupby('code ').ngroup().add(1)

### FINDING RESIDUALS 
results = sm.ols(formula='Y ~ X', data=A).fit()
Y_pred = results.predict(A[["X"]])
Y_pred
A['residual'] = A["Y"].values-Y_pred

###SIZE 
A['size']=A.groupby(['ID']).size()



###SD of residuals
for i in A['ID']:
    A['Std'] = sqrt((A['residual']-A['MEAN'])**2)/(A['size']-1)))
```

This is my dataframe [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGVLT.png)

the groups now are referred to ID (1,2,3,4,5); in each group there is rows. In each row and based by group , I would like to have a SD of the column residual.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize as I don't have enough points to just leave a comment, has to be an answer. Anyway, could you maybe try something like this:

```
new_df = df.loc[:, 'residual'].groupby(df['ID']).std()
```

Comment: I tried running your code normally, but it's clear that it's not entirely posted, so it's a little difficult to try out

Comment: i appreciate your feedback, i have tried your code, it has created SD by each group ID , however my question is to find the SD of each datapoint that exists within a group, in other word i need a code that computes the SD of my residual in each datetime and by group. thank you again